# What does "I could just spit" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, idioms, vocabulary, idioms-in-context

could you please help to decipher the meaning of the idiom "I could just spit"? I have a sentence: 
**"I'm so sick of people I could just spit",**
 but I've also found many examples in google, such as "I'm so excited I could spit" or " I'm so tired, I'm practically furious. I could just spit " Only one source, also in google :) gives the meaning "of being very angry", but how being very angry is compatible with excitement?

Suppose that doesn't mean spiting in a direct sense, does it?
Thank you very much!

Comment: The collocation ***hopping mad*** *(very angry)* has been common on both sides of the pond for centuries, but ***spitting mad*** has started to gain traction recently, [particularly is the US.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=spitting+mad%2Chopping+mad&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cspitting%20mad%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chopping%20mad%3B%2Cc0) You may also hear people use ***spit*** as a euphemism for ***shit*** in some contexts - riffing off idiomatic expressions such as *I laughed so hard I nearly shat / shit!*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"I could just spit" means the person is *very angry*.

It may be a contraction of the idiom "*I could spit nails!*"

To be fair, you could have found definitions for these [here](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/I+could+spit!) and [here](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/spit%20nails).

Comment: People used to *actually* spit as a sign of annoyance (sometimes at people as a sign of disdain). Also, some people just produce spit when they are shouting at people in anger (I'm thinking of football managers).

Comment: As I have mentioned above, in my question, I know that this can mean being angry. But, as I also mentioned in my question, how being very angry is compatible with excitement?( "I'm so excited I could spit")